# ng2-charts Firebase display bookings for certain staff ID

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, ng2-charts

When a booking is made in my app, a user selects which staff memeber they want. I am trying to display a chart on staff page to display how many orders they have had in the last 7 days.

I am using ng2-charts, data in firebase, and angular2 app.

Currently have only 2 bookings n the database. 1 for each staff member.

The code I have up to now is this, but I am getting no result back to the chart, just a flat lined result.

[image: chart]

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.af.list('/orders', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'createdAt',
        limitToLast: 1
      }
    }).subscribe((res) => {
      let lastOrder: any = res;
      var lastDate: any = lastOrder[0].createdAt;
      var x;
      var dayDuration = 86400000;//milliseconds = 24 hours
      x = 7;
      lastDate -= 6 * dayDuration;

      for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        this.barData.labels.push(this.datePipeEn.transform(lastDate, 'dd MMMM'));
        lastDate += dayDuration;
      }

      this.af.list('/orders', {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'staffId',
          equalTo: this.staffId
        }
      }).subscribe((res) => {
        this.orders = res;
        this.order = res.length;
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.barData.labels.length - 1; i++) {
          var dayValue = 0;
          for (var j = 0; j <= this.orders.length - 1; j++) {
            var orderDate = this.datePipeEn.transform(this.orders[j].createdAt, 'dd MMMM');
            if (orderDate === this.barData.labels[i]) {
              dayValue += this.orders[j].grandTotal;
            }
          }
          this.barData.datasets[0].data.push(this.order);
        }
      })
    });

  }
```

If I remove the second query in the function:

```
this.af.list('/orders', {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'staffId',
          equalTo: this.staffId
        }
      })
```

I get this result in the graph.

[image: chart2]

What I want to see is one order on the date it was made in the graph, not the count of all orders as it is showing now (without 2nd query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out myself.

In the constructor I was getting the staffId. It was getting this ok, and was pulling something an id like this through:

```
-Kr9q2Te04rlXWLyQ6PJ76F
```

My problem was, that I have a staff ID stored in the database without the Appending dash like so:

```
Kr9q2Te04rlXWLyQ6PJ76F
```

Therefore it was not a match in the query. So What I did was use the string slice() function to remove the dash then it worked!

```
let staffId = response.$key;
var str = staffId;
var res = str.slice(0, 1);
```